# 6x6 grid with no three cells of one colour in a line

Tags: mathematics

Can you paint the cells of a 6x6 grid in three colours, such that no three cells of the same colour lie on a straight line passing through their center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are

> 702 ways to paint the cells so that no row, column or diagonal contains three cells of the same color.

Of these

> All of them contain at least one line of knight's moves with three cells of the same color.

Comment: How? ILP? IHATE15CHAR

Comment: @SnySmartie No, just recursively filling the grid without violating the row/column/diagonal constraints, then checking the knight lines once the grid was full.

Comment: @SnySmartie [link to C code](https://onlinegdb.com/vNSPPKKrK8)

Comment: I confirmed via ILP your count of $702$.

Comment: @RobPratt There are no other slopes with three points in a 6x6 lattice.

Comment: Also slopes $\pm 2, \pm 1/2$.

Comment: @RobPratt Those are the lines of knight's moves in my second spoiler block.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah, got it.

Answer (score 3):

Via integer linear programming, the minimum number of monochromatic lines is

> 2.

> [image]